# how to check if accept-range is enabled on jetty server

Tags: eclipse, jetty, html5-video

I want to determine if the application that runs using jetty web server to playback video will support http server code 206 and accept byte ranges. I found a post on here related to chromes inability to allow seek function on video playback in html5, and the suggestion was to check that.

I still cannot find a way around this or some guidance on what to do to enable the server to accept byte ranges or do I need to install a new web server. Eclipse api displays the following but again not sure how to implement.

```
public boolean isAcceptRanges​()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range support is available to all Servlets and Handlers.

If you are worried about range support in static content served by Eclipse Jetty itself, use the `DefaultServlet` (supported), not a `ResourceHandler` (not supported).